# 7-Zip turn off recursive for folders that match *.*

Tags: windows, batch-file, 7zip

I'm using 7-Zip 19.00 64-bit.  I want to compress the files in a folder, but exclude sub-directories; disable recursive.

The command that I'm executing:

```
7z u -mx9 -r- -bd wwwroot.7z C:\inetpub\wwwroot\*.*
```

C:\inetpub\wwwroot\ will have sub-directories in it that are named after domains.

```
C:\inetpub\wwwroot\domain.com (directory)
C:\inetpub\wwwroot\domain.org (directory)
C:\inetpub\wwwroot\domain.net (directory)
C:\inetpub\wwwroot\images (directory)
C:\inetpub\wwwroot\javascript (directory)
C:\inetpub\wwwroot\index.html
C:\inetpub\wwwroot\robots.txt
C:\inetpub\wwwroot\favicon.ico
```

7-Zip is including sub-directories that match the wildcard; domain.com, domain.org, domain.net will be in wwwroot.7z.  images and javascript will be excluded.  index.html, robots.txt, and favicon.ico will be in wwwroot.7z as expected.

Because the folders for sites/domains will change over time, I can't hard-code the list of folders to exclude.

I've tried to use the following and none of them work as I want:

```
7z u -mx9 -r- -bd wwwroot.7z C:\inetpub\wwwroot\.
7z u -mx9 -r- -bd wwwroot.7z C:\inetpub\wwwroot\
```

I've looked in the documentation for ways to exclude by attribute but couldn't find it.  I've looked at the -x option, but it only seems to apply to files.

The system that I'm running this on is Windows Server 2012 R2.

@Mofi: wwwroot.7z should only contain files, No sub-directories.

To accomplish this task with WinRAR, I'd use this command:

```
rar u -ma5 -m5 -ep1 C:\inetpub\wwwroot\wwwroot.rar C:\inetpub\wwwroot\*.*
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The solution to compress only the files in specified directory non-recursive into a 7-Zip archive is:

```
7z.exe u -mx9 -bd -x!*\ -- wwwroot.7z C:\inetpub\wwwroot\*
```

The switch `-x!*\` results in e**x**cluding all directories in directory `C:\inetpub\wwwroot` and all files in these directories. 7-Zip does not even try to access one of the subdirectories on using this switch as it can be seen with Sysinternals (Microsoft) free tool [Process Monitor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon).

The wildcard `*` is used instead of `*.*` to compress into the archive file also files without a file extension. The 7-Zip help page **Command Line Syntax** explains the difference between `*` and `*.*` in comparison to Windows which interprets `*.*` always like `*`. WinRAR interprets `*.*` also different to `*` like 7-Zip and so also different in comparison to Windows.

**Note:** I do not understand why the default switch `-r-` even on being explicitly used on command line does not result in ignoring all files in all subdirectories as it should according to the explanation on help page **-r (Recurse subdirectories) switch** on using 7-Zip 19.00 (x86 or x64 version). `-r-` works on using `*.txt` instead of just `*`. So it looks like the behavior on adding also files in subdirectories on usage of wildcard pattern `*` or `*.*` with using implicit default `-r-` or on having specified this switch explicitly on command line is either a bug of 7-Zip 19.00 or a not good documented behavior if intentionally by design.

Comment: Alright, you now removed the `-r0` switch with respect to your (now deleted) comments, though I have to admit `-x!*\ `appears quite illogical to me, together with the (default) option `-r-`, because I would expect wildcards not to be detected at all; but even `-r -x!*\ `works unexpectedly. Anyway, I totally agree with you, `-r-` alone should be absolutely enough to prevent recursion...

Comment: @aschipfl Yes, you are right. The switches `-r`, `-r-` and `-r0` have no effect on using wildcard pattern `*.*` or `*`. The switch ``-x!*\`` is enough as I found out on testing before writing the answer. I wanted to write a 7-Zip bug report, but found before this thread [How to no recursive folder with *?](https://sourceforge.net/p/sevenzip/discussion/45798/thread/c0a7daa1/) answered by author of 7-Zip providing also the solution to use ``-x!*\``. There are many other similar threads about recursion in 7-Zip discussion forum. So it looks like this is a known issue for many years.

Comment: Thanks! @Mofi for the deep dive into the 7-zip forums.  This is the easiest way to get this to work.  I did remove the "--" from the command as it didn't seem to be needed.  If it is please reply to this comment and explain why.

Comment: @ScottJibben The switch `--` stops parsing the arguments right to it for switches. In this case it is not needed because of archive file name `wwwroot.7z` does not begin with `-` and wildcard pattern with path `C:\inetpub\wwwroot\*` does also not start with `-`. However, it is never wrong to mark the end of the list of switches with `--` with all switches specified left to `--` and the archive file name as recommended and so I always use this switch on command line on using 7-Zip, WinRAR or RAR.

Answer (score 2):

```
@echo off
setlocal

set "target=C:\inetpub\wwwroot"

dir /b /a-d "%target%\*" > "%cd%\include.tmp"

pushd "%target%\" && (
    call 7z u -mx9 -bd "%cd%\wwwroot.7z" -ir0@"%cd%\include.tmp"
    popd
)

del "%cd%\include.tmp"
```

A list file can be created with the output of `dir`, which can give a list of just files. `pushd` into the target directory and run `7z`. The `%cd%` will remain the same as delayed expansion is not used i.e. with `!cd!`. If you want script directory instead of current directory, change `%cd%` with `%~dp0`.

A list file may give you the flexibility that you may need.

Comment: The command `call` is not needed because of `7z` is an executable file with complete name `7z.exe`. Windows command processor waits for the termination of an executable run from within a batch file before it continues with next command (line) in batch file.

Comment: @Mofi, The 7-Zip installer does not install `7z.exe` in `%PATH%`. I do have a `7z.cmd` in `%PATH%`, so I do need to use `call` to complete the script. I did not remove `call` from the script because I do not know the OPs environment. With `call`, `7z` works with `.bat`, `.cmd` and `.exe` files. Your statement for my environment is false.